# Cannot access private property

Tags: magento2

What is the meaning of this error? Is the meaning of this is? I'm trying to add the extensions appearance on the product list.

main.CRITICAL: Error: Cannot access private property Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor::$pluginList in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php:429

Answer (score 0):

You are using a property or method of another class that is private

For ex: getDefaultListingMode or addToolbarBlock

Please follow this link for more info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448559/cannot-access-private-property

Happy coding